# Apache .conf in conf.d overwriting .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I'm trying to block some referrer spam server-wide by placing this inside /etc/apache2/conf.d/ref.conf :

```
<directoryMatch /var/www/vhosts/(.*)/httpdocs/>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} buttons-for-website\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} semalt\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</directoryMatch>
```

And it does work. However it looks like it's preventing my individual .htaccess files with Rewrites in them from working. They are located in /var/www/vhosts/*domain*/httpdocs/app/webroot/

How can I get both the .conf and .htaccess files to work?